# Настройка PHP сайта на Azure

Tags: php, mongodb, azure, azure-websites

Вечер добрый

У нас есть сайт который работает на:

1. PHP 5.3 и не выше, потому что нужно поставить php_http.dll версии 1.7.6.
2. Мы используем вебсайты Windows Azure.

Интересует такой вопрос:

1. На линуксовых инстансах я могу просто выйти по SSH и настраивать как мне нужно. Но как подключиться по ssh или rdp к сайт на Azure?
2. Как добавить php_http.dll к PHP который использует IIS сайта.
3. Как вообще включить версию PHP 5.3.

*UPD 1*:
Разобрался как запустить композер для Azure [вот по этой ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/africaapps/part-2-creating-a-composer-enabled-php-website-on-windows-azure-with-git-deployment).
Проблема в том что разбираюсь каким образом запустить dll mongo ([вот тут описание](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php#UseCustomPHP)).

Проблема в том что мне не удается запустить эту dll - в пых инфо секции монго так и не появляется, появляются только подключения файла:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Второй момент, при развертывании приложения запускается деплой, и там вот так:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

*UPD 2*:
Вообщем монго я смог подключить. Все делал как описанно в статье, просто не обратил внимание на один момент. Библиотеки должны быть обязательно под версию Win 32 (VC9 NTS). Иначе не подключаться и в логах будет такая фигня:

> [02-Apr-2015 02:07:33 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin/php_mongo.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Сейчас пытаюсь подключить вторую библиотку php_memcache.dll. И вот тут опять затык:

> [02-Apr-2015 03:55:59 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ bin/php_memcache.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

*UPD 3*: Все просто оказалось, после разделителя (комы), пробел не допустим...

Помогите, если знаете как )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Azure Websites не поддерживает соединение через Remote Desktope или SSH.
2. Описание того как добавлять свои собсвенные DLL можно найти [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/silverlining/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites).
3. Как включить PHP определенной версии в Azure Websites можно найти [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/app-service/configure-language-php).

UPD 1:

4. Какое-то время всё-таки еще PHP 5.3 будет поддерживаться, но включить её надо через PowerShell. Как это сделать описывалось [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63288afa-1d01-4000-b30a-c8456bc4232a/php-53-deprecation-information?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: Спасибо! Но как быть когда у нас PHP сайт допустим использует composer.phar, на обчной Unix мы делаем php composer.phar --update. Как запустить composer если мы не можем подключиться по SSH или RDP

Comment: Также обращу внимание на то, что сейчас в Azure я не вижу версии PHP 5.3 - http://joxi.ru/Ra2XoKXiDbJQmg

Comment: Если нет поддержки PHP нужной версии, то либо надо адоптировать сайт под новый пхп, либо уходить с Azure Websites. Azure Websites не очень адаптирован для полноценной разработки включающей в себя установку всяких модулей. То что вам надо это Web-Role или Worker-Role. Вот там уже и доступ по RDP, и установка своих прибамбасов, и апдейты системы делать не надо (автоматически происходят). Websites это просто лишь хостинг на базе Azure. Как и на (простом) хостинге если что-то не поддерживается, то этого не установишь просто так. Поэтому и цены низкие на Websites...

Comment: Обновил вопрос, UPDATE-2. Посмотрите пж, может быть будут мысли.